# is this an endless loop because of the exception?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
do {
      try {

        $result = $class->function_x($params); //this will fire an Exception

        break;
     } 
     catch (Exception $e) 
     {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        sleep(5);
     }
} while(true);
```

Is this an endless loop?

The method call fire an Exception so the catch write to `error_log` and wait for 5 seconds, but because of the Exception the break is not executed (to break the while) and the loop will be endless.

Is that correct or I am missing something?

Comment: i think this is not actually a coding-question but a matter for philosophical debate. personally i'd say any `do { something() } while(true)`-loop is an endless loop by default, regardless of its inner workings.

Comment: Yes. It looks like endless loop.

Comment: Worth mentioning: *Don't use exceptions for controlling code flow*. Use flags/ return values if you want it to loop again. Exceptions are for exceptional cases only.

Comment: I agree with all your comments but ts not my code i am checking an application and the code was already there and i have to fix it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$result = $class->function_x($params);` throws `Exception` it will never go to `break;`, because it will jump out to `catch` just after an `Exception`.

So **yes**, it looks like endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if `$class->function_x($params);` always throws exception, then it is endless loop.

As soon as the exception thrown, the control is given into catch block and `break` will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use break statement inside a `try catch`. You can use goto for this task. This will prevent your exceptions :

```
do {
    try {

      $result = $class->function_x($params);
      if(something) goto bre;

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        sleep(5);
    }
    bre:
} while(true);
```

Comment: its not my code i am checking an application and the code was already there and i have to fix it.Thanks